# Multichannel depending on the path with nodejs and redis

Tags: node.js, redis

i try create a multi channel depending on the path with nodejs in the same port.
For exemple (my port is 8080) :

wwww.exemple.com:8080/channel/1

wwww.exemple.com:8080/channel/2

wwww.exemple.com:8080/channel/3

wwww.exemple.com:8080/channel/4

Each url path channel corresponds to a channel redis

For exemple (channel-X) :

```
var channel = 'channel-X'
getRedis.subscribe(channel);
```

but I do not know how to link the channel and repeat the url.

here is my code to the current time.

```
socket.on('connection', function(client) {
const getRedis = redis.createClient();
const sendRedis = redis.createClient();
getRedis.subscribe('channel-1');

getRedis.on("message", function(channel, message) {
    client.send(message);
});


client.on('message', function(msg) {
    sendRedis.publish('channel-1',msg);
});


client.on('disconnect', function() {
    getRedis.quit();
    sendRedis.quit();
});
```

});

I am a bit in the fog all proposals will be welcome:)

Comment: im struggling to understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: in fact I want the client to connect to multiple channel (redis) with a single server Soket (ie a single port).
For this I thought to recover the path of the url to managed subscriptions to channels repeat

Answer (score 0):

You cannot link your channel name to your socket.io. Because socket.io client only carry latest user infor only.

Solution 1: 
You can pass the channel name from client side.

```
//Client side


var socket = new io.Socket();

socket.on('connect', function() {

socket.send({ChannelName:'channel-X',Message:'HI !!'});
});




//Server side

socket.on('connection', function(client) {

const getRedis = redis.createClient();


getRedis.on("message", function(channel, message) {
    client.send(message);
});


client.on('message', function(msg) {
    //Assume the input msg is JSON structure {ChannelName:'channel-X',Message:'HI !!'}
    var data = JSON.parse(msg);
     getRedis.subscribe(data.ChannelName);

});

});
```

Solution 2:

Use session store to store/get the channel name by socket session id.

Problem : I not understand what you need "url to managed subscriptions to channels repeat"

What is channels repeat ?

Comment: thanks your help, and i choose your first proposition but the subscription in redis channels would managed in parallel by ajax.

Comment: Solution 3: Use NowJS. :D Also, why would you need to use AJAX, if you're already using Socket.IO?

Comment: I had need ajax since i did not see how create channel dynamique otherwise with io.sokect @Steve Wang thanks for your solution